# How can I get Javascript Source(js file) from url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to retrieve source code of a javascript file( eg: xxx.js) from some url. I could get html from url but when I try to do get .js file using same method, it fails.

How can I get a whole source of js file from url?

Here's what worked for HTML :

```
$.ajax({
url : "http://localhost:8080/aaa/bbb/xxx.html",
success : function(result){
     var a= result;
    alert(a);

    }
});
```

Comment: "Did not work" is not good enough. *How* did it not work? Did you get any errors? Did you check to see what was returned? Did you look at the "Network" tab in the developer console (open it by hitting F12)?

Comment: Could you explain why you are trying to do this?

Comment: when i use alert(result), it returns undifined

Comment: cuz I need to see whole javascript source from url.(I mean xxx.js file)

Comment: Is there one specific js file you're looking for, or do you want all JS files on the page? Also, does the URL allow ajax requests ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is set to *, or to the domain that will make the requests) ?

Comment: Code *cannot access* the raw content of an arbitrary file/resource from a different domain, thanks to Same-Origin Policy, *unless* CORS is used. (Executing a script from a different domain is okay; and the side-effects it performs will apply, which is how JSONP works.)

Comment: yes, I'm looking for a specific js file on the url page. actually i wanna access html page, and parsing script src, and get the source of js file. is it impossible idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use this
    <script type="text/javascript" src="xxx.js"></script>
```

Comment: This *cannot* be used to *access* the contents if the file is on a different domain. Since the original XHR "doesn't work" I don't know what this is expected to change..